# Сайт на битриксе не работает после смены ip адреса

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Домен делегирован на Cloudflare.
Смена ip адреса сервера приводит к тому, что сайт становится недоступен с ошибкой обработки скрипта на стороне самого Битрикс.
Откат адрес на старый физический сервер возвращает сайт к жизни в течение 2-3 минут. доступы к БД в /bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php и /bitrix/.settings.php стоят одинаковые

Выдает такую ошибку:

[Bitrix\Main\DB\ConnectionException]
Mysql connect error [127.0.0.1:3312]: (1045) Access denied for user 'bitrix_user1'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES) (400)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Ну, текст ошибки намекает, что нужно дать доступ к бд для нового ip-адреса

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо большое, а где это делается? У нас есть ClaudFlare и хостинг